# how do i format Time in react.js from 2023-01-31T18:15:23.413003Z to 2023 Jan 31?

Tags: javascript, node.js, reactjs, angular, express

what would be the best way to change the time format from the long string  `2023-01-31T18:15:23.413003Z` to something more human readable like `31 Jan, 2023` and also change the time to something like `18:15:24` and not the whole string?
I already tried using the `slice()` method but how can i get the Name of the month and the number

```
    <td>{object.time_date.slice(0, 10)}</td>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use [`Intl.DateTimeFormat`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Intl/DateTimeFormat) for date/time that way you don't have to worry about importing libraries or handling localization.

Comment: can you please help me sho, hov i can implement this quicky, i have done this `<td>{Intl.DateTimeFormat().format(st.review_time)}</td>` but it display invalid time in console

Comment: `new Intl.DateTimeFormat(undefined, { weekday: 'short', year: 'numeric', month: 'short', day: 'numeric' }).format(new Date(st.review_time));`